# I need to create a logon script that adds two registry keys with the following values (P+IPAddress) & (S+IPAddress)

Tags: windows, registry

I need to create a logon script that lists the following values for each PC
(P+IPAddress) & (S+IPAddress), I managed to create the following .reg file:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Serial Numbers
"Printer"="P236"
"Scanner"="S236"
```

But I have entered these values my self, I need a script that creates a combined value (Letter + The last 3digits of the IP Address of the PC where this script runs).

I highly appreciate it if someone can help me on this.

Comment: What is meaning of "mysql" tag? you should tag it with technology you are using (batch, shell, vbscript, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single command, use Powershell like this:

```
powershell -Command "& {[system.net.dns]::gethostaddresses([system.net.dns]::gethostname()) | where { $_.addressfamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } | foreach { [microsoft.win32.registry]::setvalue('hkey_current_user\serial numbers', 'Printer', [string]::concat('P', $_.tostring().split('.')[3])) } }"
```

Not the most efficient and may have problems with multiple addresses (as it will always set to the last one) but it can be executed as a single command.

Should be easy enough to modify that command to add the Scanner bit too.

Comment: Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:235
+ & {[system.net.dns]::gethostaddresses([system.net.dns]:
| foreach { [microsoft.win32.registry]::setvalue('hkey_cu
<<<  .tostring().split('.')[3])) } }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [],
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

Comment: Using powershell is unnecessary overhead (you need to install it on all client PC).I would recommend vbscipt.

Comment: I need to create the above two registry keys with the listed values through a script and spread it through a group policy.

Comment: Simon can you please give me a script that I can type in a .reg file ?